# The message is not published on the Facebook page

Tags: facebook-graph-api

I use API 18.0
A business account is connected. Business account not verified
I do the following, in the address bar of the browser. (later it will be implemented on Delphi using the http protocol)

1. Get a short-lived user access token
   [https://www.facebook.com/v18.0/dialog/oauth?client_id={app_id}&display=popup&response_type=token&redirect_uri=https://www.facebook.com/connect/login_success.html&scope=pages_show_list,business_management,pages_read_engagement,pages_manage_metadata,pages_read_user_content,pages_manage_posts,pages_manage_engagement](https://www.facebook.com/v18.0/dialog/oauth?client_id=%7Bapp_id%7D&display=popup&response_type=token&redirect_uri=https://www.facebook.com/connect/login_success.html&scope=pages_show_list,business_management,pages_read_engagement,pages_manage_metadata,pages_read_user_content,pages_manage_posts,pages_manage_engagement)
2. Get a long-lived user access token
   [https://graph.facebook.com/v18.0/oauth/access_token?grant_type=fb_exchange_token&client_id={app_id}&client_secret={client_secret}&fb_exchange_token={short_user_token}](https://graph.facebook.com/v18.0/oauth/access_token?grant_type=fb_exchange_token&client_id=%7Bapp_id%7D&client_secret=%7Bclient_secret%7D&fb_exchange_token=%7Bshort_user_token%7D)
3. Get permanent access token
   [https://graph.facebook.com/{page_id}?fields=access_token&access_token={long_lived_token}](https://graph.facebook.com/%7Bpage_id%7D?fields=access_token&access_token=%7Blong_lived_token%7D)
4. Publish a post
   [https://graph.facebook.com/v18.0/{page_id}/feed?message=Test&link=https://test23.co&access_token={long_lived_token}](https://graph.facebook.com/v18.0/%7Bpage_id%7D/feed?message=Test&link=https://test23.co&access_token=%7Blong_lived_token%7D)
   But the message is not published.
   A list of posts is displayed.
   Help solve the problem.
   Thanks

Comment: _"But the message is not published. A list of posts is displayed."_ - that's because of your "in the address bar of the browser" approach - you are making a GET request, it needs to be a POST.

Comment: FYI: Graph API Explorer exists, you can easily test out requests in there. https://developers.facebook.com/tools/explorer/

Comment: @CBroe Thank you. The problem was in the address bar of the browser :). For me, postman is better for testing